# Sockets starts to slow down and not respond

Tags: c#, sockets, actionscript

i am developing a server (with c#) and a client (with flash, actionscript 3.0) application. Server sends data (datas are arround 90 bytes) to clients continuously and clients behave according to data they received (data is json formatted)

for a while, everything works as expected but after some time passed, clients start to receive messages laggy. they keep waiting for some time and then they behave according to last message (some messages lost). after some time passed clients starts to wait and process all the messages at the same time. I could not figured out what causing this. My network condition is stable.

here is some part of my c# code, sending message:

```
public void Send(byte[] buffer)
    {
        if (ClientSocket != null && ClientSocket.Connected)
        {
            ClientSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0, WriteCallback, ClientSocket);
        }
    }

    private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        //
    }
```

and some part of my client, receiving message (actionscript)

```
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onResponse);
function onResponse(e:ProgressEvent):void {
trace(socket.bytesAvailable);
if(socket.bytesAvailable > 0) {
    try
    {
        var serverResponse:String = socket.readUTFBytes(socket.bytesAvailable);
```

....

I hope i could explain my problem. How should i optimize my code? What can be causing lags. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to give more detail as to how you're setting up the socket (is it TCP or UDP?)

Assuming it's a TCP socket, then it would appear that your client relies on each receive call returning the same number of bytes that were sent by the server's `Send()` call. This is however not the case, and could well be the cause of your issues if a message is only being partially received on the client, or multiple messages are received at once.

For example, the server may send a 90 byte message in a single call, but your client may receive it in one 90-byte receive, or two 45-byte chunks, or even 90 x 1-byte chunks, or anything in between. Multiple messages sent by the server may also be partially combined when received by the client. E.g. two 90-byte messages may be received in a single 180-byte chunk, or a 150-byte and a 30-byte chunk, etc. etc.

You need therefore to provide some kind of framing on your messages so that when the stream of data is received by the client, it can be reliably reconstructed into individual messages.

The most basic framing mechanism would be to prefix each message sent with a fixed-length field indicating the message size. you may be able to get away with a single byte if you can guarantee that your messages will never be > 255 bytes long, which will simplify the receiving code.

On the client side, you first need to receive the length prefix, and then read up to that many bytes off the socket to construct the message data. If you receive fewer than the required number of bytes, your receiving code must wait for more data (appending it to the partially-received message when it is eventually received) until it has a complete message of the.

Once the full message is received it can be processed as you are currently.

Unfortunately I don't know ActionScript, so can't give you an example of the client-side code, but here's how you might write the server and client framing in C#:

Server side:

```
public void SendMessage(string message)
{
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    if (data.Length > byte.MaxValue) throw new Exception("Data exceeds maximum size");
    var bufferList = new[]
    {
        new ArraySegment<byte>(new[] {(byte) data.Length}),
        new ArraySegment<byte>(data)
    };
    ClientSocket.Send(bufferList);
}
```

Client side:

```
public string ReadMessage()
{
    var header = new byte[1];
    // Read the header indicating the data length
    var bytesRead = ServerSocket.Receive(header);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        var dataLength = header[0];
        // If the message size is zero, return an empty string
        if (dataLength == 0) return string.Empty;
        var buffer = new byte[dataLength];
        var position = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = ServerSocket.Receive(buffer, position, buffer.Length - position, SocketFlags.None)) > 0)
        {
            // Advance the position by the number of bytes read
            position += bytesRead;
            // If there's still more data to read before we have a full message, call Receive again
            if (position < buffer.Length) continue;
            // We have a complete message - return it.
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        }
    }
    // If Receive returns 0, the socket has been closed, so return null to indicate this.
    return null;
}
```